# Apparently random words written inside a ruby class

Tags: ruby

I came across something like this:

```
class OBRTestBase < Test::Unit::TestCase

    # some stuff here ...

    setup
    def obr_setup
        # more stuff here ...
    end

    # more stuff here ...
```

What is that `setup` line that is written? Can you just write any word inside a class, where the methods should be, without a `def` or a `@`? What does it accomplish?

I also found the word `teardown`. Can anything be written? Is there like a list of reserved words?

Comment: They are not reserved keywords. They can be any method call. If you define a class method foo() you can call this the same way.

Comment: What is the point of it? Isnt that why we have "initialize"?

Comment: the difference is that the setup method here is called on class definition, while the initialize method will be called on class instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this piece of code

```
def setup
  puts "managing external connections"
  puts "doing setup work and throwing needed exceptions"
  puts "we have successfully found the mothership"
end

def verify
    puts "class A has successfully been defined"
end
class A
    setup
    def initialize
        puts "initializing a new a"
    end
    def foo
        puts "foo"
    end
    verify
end

puts "-----start of program-----"
a = A.new()
a.foo
```

we need to connect to external resources when we startup our application. We want to be notified beforehand when these resources are not available.

Running this piece of code will have the following output

```
managing external connections
doing setup work and throwing needed exceptions
we have successfully found the mothership
class A has successfully been defined
-----start of program-----
initializing a new a
foo
=> nil
```

amongs other things this is used to start a new scope for public and private methods when they are being defined in a class..

```
Class A
  public
  public_foo(x)
    ...
  end

  private
  private_bar(x)
    ...
  end
end
```

Note that the public_foo method is defined public on class definition. and not when the class is being instatiated.

Comment: Why wouldn't the setup and verify be added at the beginning and end of the constructor?

Comment: Suppose the constructor needs a value written in a file on disk. We could check the existance of the file each time the user wants to call a method, and open the file if it exists. But this takes a lot of work for each time a simple method is called. Since we know we need this file each time this method is called (and it will fail otherwise) we can open/create this file when the program loads rather then when the calls a runtime method.

Comment: also when you add them to the constructor you call these methods each time you create a new A. while when you do then at class definition you will only call the method 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby code, you write methods, and they would be executed in the order they are read. If you write `setup` (assuming it is a method because it would be useless if it were a local variable), within the class `OBRTestBase`, it will be executed within the context of `OBRTestBase`. If there is no such method or a local variable, then it will raise an error.

Comment: Yes, methods are executed when they are called. They are called when you write them.

Comment: You are calling a method @Dbugger, that is what `setup` is doing. When Ruby reaches the `setup` line, `self` is set to `OBRTestCase` - so `setup` is calling the method `setup` on the `OBRTestCase` class.

Comment: isnt that the same as just using "initialize", which would have an implicit call?

Answer (score 0):

`setup` in this context is a method that available while the class was being loaded. It might be injected into the current context by a number of methods.

To find where this method was defined in your project you can print the source location of that method:

```
p method(:setup).source_location
```

Comment: It could be inherited. To know exactly where it is coming in from you can use the source location.

Comment: What does it mean that is "available" while the class is loading?

Comment: "available" as in defined on `self`. When the class is loading `self` would the the Class being loaded. So method already defined on the class.